# Why when I join these two geographic datasets together do some values get filled with NAs?

Tags: r, gis

I'm trying to join two datasets together- a dataset from Natural Earth subset to contain only countries in Europe (europe_map) and a list of locations in Europe (europe_places).

Here is the headers of the datasets:

europe_places

```
Simple feature collection with 23 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -9.1393 ymin: 38.7223 xmax: 24.1052 ymax: 58.97
geographic CRS: WGS 84
First 10 features:
      Location Year Country Continent                  geometry
1        Paris 2008  France    Europe    POINT (2.3522 48.8566)
2    Stavanger 2009  Norway    Europe      POINT (5.7331 58.97)
3        Paris 2009  France    Europe    POINT (2.3522 48.8566)
4       Berlin 2010 Germany    Europe      POINT (13.405 52.52)
5       Prague 2011 Czechia    Europe   POINT (14.4378 50.0755)
6  Piancavallo 2012   Italy    Europe  POINT (12.5166 46.10768)
7     Budapest 2012 Hungary    Europe   POINT (19.0402 47.4979)
8       Aprica 2013   Italy    Europe POINT (10.15177 46.15486)
9       Vienna 2014 Austria    Europe   POINT (16.3738 48.2082)
10    Folgaria 2014   Italy    Europe  POINT (11.17205 45.9162)
```

europe_map

```
    Simple feature collection with 6 features and 94 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -8.144824 ymin: 41.89756 xmax: 40.12832 ymax: 60.83188
geographic CRS: WGS 84
        featurecla scalerank LABELRANK        Country SOV_A3 ADM0_DIF LEVEL              TYPE
5  Admin-0 country         6         6        Vatican    VAT        0     2 Sovereign country
28 Admin-0 country         4         6 United Kingdom    GB1        1     2           Country
29 Admin-0 country         4         6 United Kingdom    GB1        1     2           Country
30 Admin-0 country         3         6 United Kingdom    GB1        1     2           Country
31 Admin-0 country         1         2 United Kingdom    GB1        1     2           Country
33 Admin-0 country         1         3        Ukraine    UKR        0     2 Sovereign country
            ADMIN ADM0_A3 GEOU_DIF        GEOUNIT GU_A3 SU_DIF        SUBUNIT SU_A3 BRK_DIFF
5         Vatican     VAT        0        Vatican   VAT      0        Vatican   VAT        0
28         Jersey     JEY        0         Jersey   JEY      0         Jersey   JEY        0
29       Guernsey     GGY        0       Guernsey   GGY      0       Guernsey   GGY        0
30    Isle of Man     IMN        0    Isle of Man   IMN      0    Isle of Man   IMN        0
31 United Kingdom     GBR        0 United Kingdom   GBR      0 United Kingdom   GBR        0
33        Ukraine     UKR        0        Ukraine   UKR      0        Ukraine   UKR        0
             NAME      NAME_LONG BRK_A3       BRK_NAME       BRK_GROUP ABBREV POSTAL
5         Vatican        Vatican    VAT        Vatican            <NA>   Vat.      V
28         Jersey         Jersey    JEY         Jersey Channel Islands   Jey.     JE
29       Guernsey       Guernsey    GGY       Guernsey Channel Islands Guern.     GG
30    Isle of Man    Isle of Man    IMN    Isle of Man            <NA>  IoMan     IM
31 United Kingdom United Kingdom    GBR United Kingdom            <NA>   U.K.     GB
33        Ukraine        Ukraine    UKR        Ukraine            <NA>   Ukr.     UA
                                              FORMAL_EN FORMAL_FR              NAME_CIAWF
5                             State of the Vatican City      <NA> Holy See (Vatican City)
28                                  Bailiwick of Jersey      <NA>                  Jersey
29                                Bailiwick of Guernsey      <NA>                Guernsey
30                                                 <NA>      <NA>             Isle of Man
31 United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland      <NA>          United Kingdom
33                                              Ukraine      <NA>                 Ukraine
               NOTE_ADM0 NOTE_BRK          NAME_SORT NAME_ALT MAPCOLOR7 MAPCOLOR8 MAPCOLOR9
5                   <NA>     <NA> Vatican (Holy See) Holy See         1         3         4
28 U.K. crown dependency     <NA>             Jersey     <NA>         6         6         6
29 U.K. crown dependency     <NA>           Guernsey     <NA>         6         6         6
30 U.K. crown dependency     <NA>        Isle of Man     <NA>         6         6         6
31                  <NA>     <NA>     United Kingdom     <NA>         6         6         6
33                  <NA>     <NA>            Ukraine     <NA>         5         1         6
   MAPCOLOR13  POP_EST POP_RANK GDP_MD_EST POP_YEAR LASTCENSUS GDP_YEAR
5           2     1000        3          0     2015         NA        0
28          3    98840        8       5080     2017       2001     2015
29          3    66502        8       3465     2017       2001     2015
30          3    88815        8       7428     2017       2006     2014
31          3 64769452       16    2788000     2017       2011     2016
33          3 44033874       15     352600     2017       2001     2016
                      ECONOMY              INCOME_GRP WIKIPEDIA FIPS_10_ ISO_A2 ISO_A3
5  2. Developed region: nonG7 2. High income: nonOECD         0       VT     VA    VAT
28 2. Developed region: nonG7 2. High income: nonOECD        NA       JE     JE    JEY
29 2. Developed region: nonG7 2. High income: nonOECD        NA       GK     GG    GGY
30 2. Developed region: nonG7 2. High income: nonOECD        NA       IM     IM    IMN
31    1. Developed region: G7    1. High income: OECD        NA       UK     GB    GBR
33       6. Developing region  4. Lower middle income        NA       UP     UA    UKR
   ISO_A3_EH ISO_N3 UN_A3 WB_A2 WB_A3   WOE_ID WOE_ID_EH
5        VAT    336   336  <NA>  <NA> 23424986  23424986
28       JEY    832   832    JG   CHI 23424857  23424857
29       GGY    831   831    JG   CHI 23424827  23424827
30       IMN    833   833    IM   IMY 23424847  23424847
31       GBR    826   826    GB   GBR      -90  23424975
33       UKR    804   804    UA   UKR 23424976  23424976
                                                                                                                                                                  WOE_NOTE
5                                                                                                                                               Exact WOE match as country
28                                                                                                                                              Exact WOE match as country
29                                                                                                                                              Exact WOE match as country
30                                                                                                                                              Exact WOE match as country
31 Eh ID includes Channel Islands and Isle of Man. UK constituent countries of England (24554868), Wales (12578049), Scotland (12578048), and Northern Ireland (20070563).
33                                                                                                                                              Exact WOE match as country
   ADM0_A3_IS ADM0_A3_US ADM0_A3_UN ADM0_A3_WB CONTINENT REGION_UN       SUBREGION
5         VAT        VAT         NA         NA    Europe    Europe Southern Europe
28        JEY        JEY         NA         NA    Europe    Europe Northern Europe
29        GGY        GGY         NA         NA    Europe    Europe Northern Europe
30        IMN        IMN         NA         NA    Europe    Europe Northern Europe
31        GBR        GBR         NA         NA    Europe    Europe Northern Europe
33        UKR        UKR         NA         NA    Europe    Europe  Eastern Europe
               REGION_WB NAME_LEN LONG_LEN ABBREV_LEN TINY HOMEPART MIN_ZOOM MIN_LABEL
5  Europe & Central Asia        7        7          4    4        1        0       5.0
28 Europe & Central Asia        6        6          4   NA       NA        0       5.0
29 Europe & Central Asia        8        8          6   NA       NA        0       5.0
30 Europe & Central Asia       11       11          5   NA       NA        0       5.0
31 Europe & Central Asia       14       14          4   NA        1        0       1.7
33 Europe & Central Asia        7        7          4   NA        1        0       3.0
   MAX_LABEL      NE_ID WIKIDATAID         NAME_AR       NAME_BN                NAME_DE
5       10.0 1159321407       Q237       الفاتيكان ভ্যাটিকান সিটি           Vatikanstadt
28      10.0 1159320725       Q785           جيرزي         জার্সি                 Jersey
29      10.0 1159320715     Q25230          غيرنزي          <NA>               Guernsey
30      10.0 1159320721      Q9676       جزيرة مان   আইল অব ম্যান            Isle of Man
31       6.7 1159320713       Q145 المملكة المتحدة       যুক্তরাজ্য Vereinigtes Königreich
33       7.0 1159321345       Q212        أوكرانيا        ইউক্রেন                Ukraine
          NAME_EN             NAME_ES     NAME_FR          NAME_EL      NAME_HI
5    Vatican City Ciudad del Vaticano     Vatican         Βατικανό    वैटिकन नगर
28         Jersey              Jersey      Jersey          Τζέρσεϊ         जर्सी
29       Guernsey            Guernsey   Guernesey         Γκέρνσεϊ        ग्वेर्नसे
30    Isle of Man         Isla de Man  île de Man    Νήσος του Μαν  मनुष्य का टापू
31 United Kingdom         Reino Unido Royaume-Uni Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο यूनाइटेड किंगडम
33        Ukraine             Ucrania     Ukraine         Ουκρανία         युक्रेन
               NAME_HU       NAME_ID            NAME_IT    NAME_JA     NAME_KO
5              Vatikán       Vatikan Città del Vaticano   バチカン 바티칸 시국
28              Jersey        Jersey  Baliato di Jersey ジャージー     저지 섬
29 Guernsey Bailiffség      Guernsey           Guernsey ガーンジー     건지 섬
30                 Man     Pulau Man       Isola di Man     マン島       맨 섬
31  Egyesült Királyság Britania Raya        Regno Unito   イギリス        영국
33             Ukrajna       Ukraina            Ucraina ウクライナ  우크라이나
               NAME_NL         NAME_PL     NAME_PT        NAME_RU        NAME_SV
5         Vaticaanstad         Watykan    Vaticano        Ватикан  Vatikanstaten
28              Jersey          Jersey      Jersey         Джерси         Jersey
29            Guernsey        Guernsey    Guernsey         Гернси       Guernsey
30                 Man       Wyspa Man Ilha de Man     остров Мэн    Isle of Man
31 Verenigd Koninkrijk Wielka Brytania Reino Unido Великобритания Storbritannien
33            Oekraïne         Ukraina     Ucrânia        Украина        Ukraina
            NAME_TR                                 NAME_VI NAME_ZH
5           Vatikan                           Thành Vatican  梵蒂冈
28           Jersey                                  Jersey  澤西島
29         Guernsey                                Guernsey  根西岛
30        Man Adası                                 Đảo Man  马恩岛
31 Birleşik Krallık Vương quốc Liên hiệp Anh và Bắc Ireland    英国
33          Ukrayna                                 Ukraina  乌克兰
                         geometry
5  POLYGON ((12.43916 41.89839...
28 POLYGON ((-2.018652 49.2312...
29 POLYGON ((-2.512305 49.4945...
30 POLYGON ((-4.412061 54.1853...
31 MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.667676 5...
33 MULTIPOLYGON (((38.21436 47...
```

I used the following code to join the datasets together:

```
europe.map1<-st_join(europe_places, europe_map, by="Country")
```

But when I did the entries for Venice, Lisbon and Copenhagen had NA values despite the entry for `Country` containing values that matched those in the europe_map dataset.
[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get an error or warning. `st_join` is for spatial joins & needs a geometry function as an argument, not a `by=` like a `left_join`.  You might want to clarify what output you expect. `sf` objects are typically easiest to work with when they have only one geometry column.
The NA's are due to the type of spatial join, default might be `st_within`. All of the NA cities are probably on the water, therefore on or over the edge of the country shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up on the comments above, you have not specified the spatial join correctly. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
europe.map1<- st_join(europe_places, europe_map,
                    join=st_within, # always best to specify the method
                    left=TRUE)
```

This should work for you. That said, you may want to switch the order of `europe_places` and `europe_map`. I am not sure about your goal. You can find more information about the different types of spatial joins within the `sf` package [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_pred.html).